# The window terminated unexpectedly

Tags: windows, powershell, visual-studio-code, uninstallation, restart

Whenever i use VS code this error always pop and i had to restart vscode again and again please help me with this error.

[image]

I tried reinstalling but doesn't work.

Comment: `oom` suggest that you're running out of memory; hopefully the linked duplicate offers solutions.

Comment: why don't you search for the message in the error box, very likely you are not the first